# AWS Codedeploy agent starts up as active(exited) on ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-16.04

When I start/restart the codedeploy-agent service on my ubuntu 16.04 instance, it immediately exits. I've had this service running(active) for several weeks leading up to this issue. I've encountered this issue in the past and had to resort to recreating a fresh EC2 instance in order to get the service back up and running. I'd prefer to not have to do that going forward.

I've checked that the IAM permissions are set correctly and confirmed that they are. I've confirmed that my other instances in the same region are running the codedeploy-agent service with no issues. Disk space is free. I've tried restarting/stopping/starting the instance. See below

`sudo service codedeploy-agent status`

```
codedeploy-agent.service - LSB: AWS CodeDeploy Host Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/codedeploy-agent; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2019-07-19 18:25:53 UTC; 5min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2869 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/codedeploy-agent stop (code=killed, signal=TERM)
  Process: 2877 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/codedeploy-agent start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
CPU: 0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I am encountering a similar issue. Been using Code Deploy for the longest time with no problems. But now every now and then the agent will exit. I can sometimes fix this by running sudo service codedeploy-agent start, but not always.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sudo rm /opt/codedeploy-agent/state/.pid/codedeploy-agent.pid
sudo rm /opt/codedeploy-agent/state/.pid/codedeploy-agent.pid.lock
sudo service codedeploy-agent restart
```